# Python: Modifying class variables outside module has no effect

Tags: python, class, types, module, reference

I am trying to create a system where I can mutate the values of A as easily as possible. When I import A into various other modules and modify the fields of A
they seem to remain changed in the foreign module but are unchanged in A's native module.

```
# module name a.py

import b

class A:
    x = 0

    @classmethod
    def call_mutate_A_from_B(cls):
        b_object = b.B()
        b_object.mutate_A() # change does not seem to stay in effect upon 
                            # return

        print(cls.x) # prints 0

def main():
    A.call_mutate_A_from_B()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# module name b.py

from a import A

class B: # in a different module
    def mutate_A():
       A.x = 2
```

Is this the expected behaviour? I don't think it is. Should I create an object representation of A not treat is as a static class?

Comment: It is not clear why you thought that setting a local variable in an instance method on an unrelated class would change a class attribute on the current class, but... it won't.

Comment: How are you using these classes and modules, can you show `main`?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the example. it's supposed to be A.x = 2 not x = 2

Comment: Your example code is incomplete and confusing.  Rewrite your question to contain __complete, runnable code that demonstrates the behavior__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question: yes, this is the expected behavior. Let us say that a module A is imported by another module B. When we `import A`, two things happen:

- All the object definitions of the imported module A are imported into B.
- Any executable statements in A are executed (only once).

To elaborate on the first point, all the definitions of classes, functions, variables etc. from A are imported into B. It is safe to say that B now has its own working copies of module A's contents to work with. Changing any aspect of these copies will **not** have any effect on the original definitions, meaning that these changes will **not** be reflected in A (the imported module).

I hope this clears your question. You can read more about how modules work in the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer I was looking for.